# how to make a function works on data frame instead a column?

Tags: r

I implement a small loop which calculate an output for me perfectly as I want

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
n<- colSums(df == 1)
N <- nrow(df)
tt <- as.data.frame(seq(1,N, by=1))
xi <-cumsum(df)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  m<- abs((xi[i,]/n)-(tt[i,]/N))/sqrt((n+N/n*N))
  df$newcolumn[i] <- m
}
```

now I want to do the same but for many columns instead of only one 
what changes are n, xi and tt

Lets now create a data frame

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I can calculate all the corresponding parameters, N, n, xi and tt as follows

```
    n<- colSums(df2 == 1)
    N <- nrow(df2)
    tt <- as.data.frame(seq(1,N, by=1))
    xi <-cumsum(df2)
```

Now I want to do the same for loop which was calculating for only one column , I want to calculate for column 1 to length of df2

I tried to do it like below but did not work 
any idea, a better way to do so , all are appreciated

```
newcolumn = matrix (0, nrow(df), ncol(df))
results = matrix (0, nrow(df), ncol(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {                    
  for (j in 1:length(df)) {               
       m<- abs((xi[i,j]/n[j])-(tt[i,j]/N))/sqrt((n[j]+N/n[j]*N))
       newcolumn[i,j] <- m
       results <- rbind(results, newcolumn[,j]) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need a loop here? `abs((xi/n-tt[,1]/N))/sqrt((n+N/n*N))` gives the same result as `df$newcolumn`   For the many columns, I guess `lapply(df2, function(x) ...)` would work

Comment: @akrun if it gives the same results, not really! I just need the results for a data frame instead a single column :-p does not matter if it is a loop or a single line command as long as it gives me the answer !

Comment: Try `sapply(df2, function(x) {n <- sum(x==1); N <- length(x); tt <- seq(1, N, by=1); xi <- cumsum(x); abs((xi/n-tt/N))/sqrt((n+N/n*N))})`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much!!!!! I learned something today because of you :-D thanks you solved my problem !!!!

Comment: @akrun however, if I ever wanted to do that through loops, how could I solve the problem? where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: In your loop, I find `df` instead of `df2`.  Did you changed `df` to `df2`?

Comment: @akrun Yes, I did ! but it give me error like (Error in newcolumn[i, j] <- m : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rbind(results, newcolumn[, j]) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Comment: Updated with a possible loop solution as well

Comment: @akrun thank you so much!!!! I wish i could like 1000 times :-) thanks again man I accepted and liked your solution

Comment: @akrun I face one problem , xi <- cumsum(x) does not calculate for each column separately and when I use something like apply(x,2,cumsum) , it goes to infinity (the memory of my laptop goes crazy ) if you find any solution for it, let me know please

Comment: I did noticed that, but when I tried it on the example data you provided, it seemed to calculate for each column separately as the results from `apply` and simple `cumsum` was the same.  How about `mutate_each` from `dplyr`?  But I think even `lapply(df2, cumsum)` would be okay, or `mutate_each(df2, funs(cumsum))`

Comment: @akrun lapply has the same problem generate a list and does not seem to calculate for each column unless I don't know how to convert it to a way which then link the results to each column   . on the other hand, mutate_each gives an error like , no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Your original dataset `df2` was data.frame.  So, probably you have now a matrix. Convert that to data.frame and try with `cumsum`

Comment: @akrun thanks again :-) seems like it works I first convert the matrix to data frame by output3<- data.frame(output2) then I simply did m<- cumsum(output3) which gave me a data frame with a good dimension :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
  res <-  sapply(df2, function(x) {
            n <- sum(x==1)
            N <- length(x)
            tt <- seq(1, N, by=1)
            xi <- cumsum(x)
           abs((xi/n-tt/N))/sqrt((n+N/n*N))})
```

Or you could vectorize some of the steps

```
n <- colSums(df2==1)
N <- nrow(df2)
tt <- seq(1, N, by=1)
xi <- cumsum(df2)
res1 <- abs(xi/n[col(xi)]-tt/N)/sqrt(n+N/n*N)[col(xi)]
identical(as.data.frame(res), res1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or using loop

```
res2 <-  matrix (0, nrow(df2), ncol(df2))
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
for(j in 1:length(df2)){
  res2[i,j] <- abs((xi[i,j]/n[j])-(tt[i,1]/N))/sqrt((n[j]+N/n[j]*N))
 }
}

all.equal(res, res2,check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

where

```
n<- colSums(df2 == 1)
N <- nrow(df2)
tt <- as.data.frame(seq(1,N, by=1))
xi <-cumsum(df2)
```